# Targeting an inputs value inside an HTML collection

Tags: javascript

I am making a card flipping game and I'm stuck on a particular function. During gameplay, cards disappear (by changing class name)

```
function reShuffle() {
var cds = document.getElementsByClassName('nocard');

for (var t = 0; t < cds.length; t++) {
    console.log(cds[t]);
    ///i need to target an input within a div, inside another div, inside cds[t];
    ///make sense?
    }
}
```

The function above is sending a collection of HTML to my console.  The console looks like this: (the html collection are the items that the user got points for, so the console return can vary based on user actions)
[image]

Now, i want to target all inputs inside of divs that have class 'nocard', but not the other inputs of the same name.  When I tried to make a loop to call the class 'fntCls' the console returned all of the inputs and not just the ones inside of the divs with class 'nocard'.

I hope i explained this right.  I need to target the values of class 'fntCls' that are in the cards that have the class 'nocard', but not the ones that are in class 'cards'.

I went to make a fiddle, but it doesn't work properly with the way i use localStorage.  So i can post a git if necessary.  Also, i should mention that i am not using Jquery or any other libraries.  I would like "vanilla" JavaScript assistance.

I'm sorry if this is long, or not precise to describe what i need.  I really struggled to find the right words to explain what is going on here, it's my first time trying to do this particular action.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using document.querySelectorAll('.nocard input.fntCls') to get all the inputs with the class fntCls, inside all the elements with the nocard class.

Comment: i will right now and get back to you.

Comment: I was able to do what i desire with the querySelectorAll option.   Please post as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using document.querySelectorAll you can target the inputs like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nocard input.fntCls')
```

The .nocard targets the elements with the class nocard and input.fntCls will target the inputs inside those elements with the fntCls class.